# Visual Studio 2013 Express C# XAML editor and .cs [design]

Tags: c#, forms, xaml

Got an example GUI including a "MainWindow.xaml" file

No XAML Editor appears when I right-click a .xaml file and go to  ["Open With"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dCVRB.jpg) and it seems to be selecting XML Editor automatically.

Double-clicking the file from the Solutions tab or using (shift+F7) shows the [xaml code and it's readable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6Dip.jpg) but I expected more text highlights and better intellisense.

Additionally, is there any way to view the xaml file as a cs [design] ??

Comment: Why not open VS and open the file from inside VS ?

Comment: That window is from clicking "Open With" inside Visual Studio

Comment: And what happens when you doubleclick the xaml file in the SolutionExplorer ?

Comment: I also have ContextMenuItem `ViewDesigner` ( `SHIFT + F7` )

Comment: @Nudity I've replied in an edit.

Comment: Try dragging the XAML file into Visual Studio

Comment: Same result as double-clicking or using (shift+F7)

Comment: Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer : Is the "Enable XAML Designer" checkbox checked? As for colors and stuff, that's Options -> Environment -> Fonts and Colors

Comment: XAML Designer isn't an option and in Fonts and Colors there's no option for XAML either.